# 'Integrating JavaScript Components and Extensions' and how to send state changes from JS back to server?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

By following tutorial on https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html I created a component for FullCalendar js library. It works nice but I can't still figure out how to send changes in getState() on JS side back to server side to persist. Vaadin sends me serverside state object to JavaScript and I can access it as `'this.getState().property'` in my JS component part. Now when user does some browser changes to Fullcalendar (e.g. switches view  from month to week) and can detect it and store it back to state object `"this.getState().viewName='yyy'"` But these changes are not synced back to server so my server side code can't see it in my state JavaBean ...

I also read this article http://vaadinsnippets.blogspot.cz/2012/10/smooth-integration-of-vaadin-7-and.html but still no idea how it should work like. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really change "shared state" on the client.
From the Vaadin docs https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-shared-state.html:

> [shared state] should be considered read-only on the client-side, as
>   it is not serialized back to the server-side.

I think what you're looking for is RPC:

> RPC calls from the client-side to the server-side are made through an
>   RPC interface that extends the ServerRpc interface. A server RPC
>   interface simply defines any methods that can be called through the
>   interface.

https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-rpc.html